# Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 10 file: Code.gs

Tags: google-sheets, syntax-error

Full disclosure, I am *very* much not a coder. I'm trying to send email notifications from Google Sheets to tell me when a value drops below a certain threshold, but I keep getting an error message whenever I try to save it.

Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 10 file: Code.gs

Here's my code:

```
function checkValue()
  {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var checkValue = sheet.getRange("D5").getValue();

if(checkValue < 0.4)
  {
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient:"email@email.com", subject:"Subject", body:"Body");
  }
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing a bracket `}`!

Try this:

```js
function checkValue()
  {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var checkValue = sheet.getRange("D5").getValue();

if(checkValue < 0.4)
  {
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient:"email@email.com", subject:"Subject", body:"Body");
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't seem like that quite fixed the issue (although I was missing the bracket, so big thanks on that one!) Any other ideas?? Again, HUGE thank you!!